# Time gets 3 hours forward always on midnight

Tags: centos, ntp, scientific-linux, ntpd, chrony

Every time I sync  the time on a CentOS 7 (Scientific Linux 7) server virtualized on VMware ESXi, I arrive the next day to find that the time gets 3 hours forward. I did a cronjob to write the time every 5 miniutes and I noticed that when the time is `22:55`, the next time written is `2:00`. This is my `/etc/ntp.conf` which is supposed to sync with a local NTP server

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict localhost
restrict -6 ::1
server xx.xx.xx.xx prefer iburst
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
disable monitor
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
```

I configured `chronyd` with only `server` directive as above but I get the same behavior.

`/etc/adjtime` contents:

```
0.0 0 0.0
0
UTC
```

The way I sync the time:

1. Stop `ntpd`
2. `ntpdate xx.xx.xx.xx`
3. `timedatectl set-ntp true`
4. Start `ntpd`.

The timezone is correct through `/etc/localtime` link, `tzselect`, and `timedatectl set-timezone` commands.

Comment: What timezone are you in? Is the system's hardware clock set to UTC time?

Comment: Asia/Amman. From the `/etc/adjtime` it seems yes.

Comment: Ad is the host machine of the VM a Windows machine or another machine running in the UTC+3 timezone?

Comment: No. All of our servers are running in an ESXi hypervisor.

Comment: Please add output from `/sbin/adjtimex --print` to your question.

Comment: Command not found .........

Comment: Still, command not found. Even in `yum` I could not find anything related.

Comment: Oh well. I'll see how else to get the drift variables out of the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you most likely have an issue with VMWare integrated time sync.
By default your esxi insure that the clock of your guest machines are synced with its clock.
If you want to disable the sync between your esxi clock and your guest VM you can.
See the [VMWare KB1189](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1189) :

- power off you VM
- connect to the ESXI in SSH
- edit the file /vmfs/volumes/datastore_name/vm_name/vm_name.vmx
- change thos value to `0` or `FALSE` (it will depend on the type of vmware product you use:

> tools.syncTime = "0"  or "FALSE"
>   time.synchronize.continue = "0"  or "FALSE"
>   time.synchronize.restore = "0"  or "FALSE"
>   time.synchronize.resume.disk = "0"  or "FALSE"
>   time.synchronize.shrink = "0"  or "FALSE"
>   time.synchronize.tools.startup = "0"  or "FALSE"
>   time.synchronize.tools.enable = "0"  or "FALSE"
>   time.synchronize.resume.host = "0"  or "FALSE"

**Important note:**
Before Doing that I would suggest you to check if the clock of your ESX is properly configure and that it's not the problem, it's easier to keep your esxi clock sync so all your vm will have a correct clock.